# FB-Share page that contains an image generated dynamically

Tags: php, facebook, image, share, dynamically-generated

I have a page in which a user can see a test result. There is a png image generated by this script

```
 header('Content-type: image/png');

 $jpg_image = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['immagine']);
 $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);
 $font_path = 'arialbd.ttf';
 $text = $_GET['nome'];
 imagettftext($jpg_image, 55, 0, 50, 64, $white, $font_path, $text);
 imagepng($jpg_image,NULL,0,NULL);
 imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

At the end of the test the users can share the result on facebook. So I need to share through facebook the image generated with php script.
How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Create a unique url. And then add og:image on that contains a link to the image you generate. Then the user share the unique link

Answer (score 0):

There is no script that can directly change the share button and input the dynamically generated image. The way you can do this is to store the image generated automatically somewhere on the drive, and put a facebook share button. In the field of share that comes, tell the user before to upload the image created in his gallery(if he is not allowed to view all pictures). You can't change FB Share code and directly share the image generated.